# How to send byte array via TCP when using newLISP

Tags: newlisp

I want to send two bytes which represent an unsigned short in big-endian to server via TCP. But net-send only supports string parameter.
Could anyone tell me how to do this with newLISP?

Answer (score 2):

It works now.
CODE: SELECT ALL

> (set 'socket (net-connect "localhost" 8889))
>   16
>   (set 'size (pack ">d" 19))
>   "\000\019"
>   (net-send socket size)
>   2

pack returns a string buffer that contains my two bytes, net-send sends the string to server.
My C++ server got two bytes, 0 and 19.
Thanks.